# Qt Creator shows errors in fresh project, but code compiles fine

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

Context: I recently switched from debian stable to debian testing so I have updated several hundred packages since the last time I used QT creator.

When I create a new project in QT creator I am greeted with many error messages.

For example, here are the errors for the autogenerated main.cpp class in a fresh project:

```
cstddef:50:10: fatal error: 'stddef.h' file not found
error: variable has incomplete type 'QApplication'
forward declaration of 'QApplication'
unknown type name 'MainWindow'
```

When I open up previous projects that I know have no errors they also show a whole bunch of similar errors.

However, all of these projects build and run just fine.

What is causing this?

Comment: Are those errors from your IDE, or the compiler?

Comment: I assume you mean errors shown in Qt Creator editing view, and clarified the title. If I got it wrong, please roll back my edit or edit further.

Comment: @Brian They are errors shown inline with the code in qt creator and also in the "Issues" tab. The code compiles fine through qt creator without any compiler errors.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem in this [bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=952718).

The `libclang-common-8-dev` package needs to be installed. After installing this package and restarting qt creator all of the errors went away.

Comment: Thanks, that saved me some headache. I'm using Kubuntu 20.04 with the distro qt packages and figured I was missing some package but there was no clear clue what was missing.

Comment: I had to add libclang-common-9-dev on Lubuntu 20.04.
Now it compiles fine.

Comment: Thank you! I'm also in Kubuntu 20.04 and this has giving me a headache!

Comment: Great answer!  Strange that 2 other SO posts that don't have this answer are higher Google results

Comment: Thanks. It helped me with the Mint 20.3 distro. It couldn't find any responding pieces (like declarations) outside current file, hence "semantic issue" error everywhere.

Answer (score 8):

After seeing JShorthouse's answer, I disabled all the Clang related plugins. Then, everything started working like normal after restarting QT creator.

Find the plugins list in the menu under Help->About Plugins...

Comment: In my case, I only needed to disable ClangCodeModel.